No output from IPC::Open3
When I execute the following synopsis for IPC::Open3:
# send STDOUT and STDERR to already open handle
open my $outfile, '>>', 'output.txt' or die "open failed: $!";
my $pid = open3('<&STDIN', $outfile, undef, 'ls');
waitpid($pid, 0);

Why is there no output in "output.txt"?

The behavior of IPC::Open3 (And IPC::Open2) when given an open file handle as one of the in or out arguments is poorly described in the documentation. When you pass just the filehandle as chld_out or chld_err, whatever is currently open on it is closed, and it's reused as the read end of a pipe (With the write end connected to the executed process's standard output or standard error). The opposite ends are naturally used for the chld_in argument.
A demonstration:
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.36;
use IPC::Open3;

# send STDOUT and STDERR to already open handle
open my $outfile, '>>', 'output.txt' or die "open failed: $!";
say '$outfile is a file handle' if -f $outfile;
my $pid = open3('<&STDIN', $outfile, undef, 'ls');
if (-f $outfile) {
    say '$outfile is still a file';
} elsif (-p _) {
    say '$outfile is now a pipe handle';
}
say scalar <$outfile>; # First file in directory
waitpid $pid, 0;

produces the output:
$outfile is a file handle
$outfile is now a pipe handle
a file name

If you use the >&HANDLE version of the output argument, passing the underlying file descriptor of the handle as HANDLE, it instead uses that as the executed process's standard output:
my $pid = open3('<&STDIN', sprintf(">&%d", fileno $outfile), undef, 'ls')

will fill your output.txt with the output of running ls as desired.

Side note: Use IPC::Run instead.

Re "is poorly described in the documentation", The OP's code is straight out of the docs

Your solution is buggy too. (Well, it was buggy. It might have been fixed.) Passing a file descriptor to <& or >& appears to work, but it has issues. If I'm remembering the details correctly, a close fails in the child. If I'm guessing correctly, this can prevent EOF from being reached on that handle.

The Synopsis is wrong.
[Update: The documentation has fixed in upcoming Perl 5.42.]
To send the output to a handle, one must pass a string that starts with >&.

If $chld_out or $chld_err begins with >&, then the child will send output directly to that filehandle.

The code in the Synopsis doesn't do this, so it doesn't work, so I've reported the bug here.
Quick fix:
open local *OUTFILE, '>>', 'output.txt' or die "open failed: $!";
my $pid = open3('<&STDIN', '>&OUTFILE', undef, 'ls');
waitpid($pid, 0);

Better fix:
open3 is a really low-level interface. It has large pitfalls besides the issues with its documentation. I recommend using IPC::Run instead. Not only is its interface cleaner, it helps avoids these pitfalls. (It's documentation also has shortcomings, but they're not as bad as open3's.)
run [ "ls" ], ">", "output.txt", "2>&1";

